# onkeyup in HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I am working with HTML and JQuery. Now I am trying onkeyup in HTML. But It doesn't worked.
HTML:

```
 <p>A function is triggered when the user releases a key in the input field. The function transforms the character to upper case.</p>
```

Enter your name:

JS;

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("fname");
x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/qsxccd36/

Comment: You don't need JS to do this. You can just uppercase the value in CSS :

    `<input style="text-transform:uppercase"/>`

Comment: Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/qsxccd36/3/ . Your function is not available in markup. Moved it in markup.

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
<input type="text" id="fname">
```

Use jquery -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fname').on('keyup', function() {
        $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `input` event instead of `keyup`

> Occurs when the text content of an element is changed through the user
>   interface.

```
$('#fname').on('input', function() {
        $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qsxccd36/2/)